# Array filter in Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, filter, swift3

I have a piece of code. I am not getting whats going inside in this code. Can anybody explain it?

```
 let wordFreqs = [("k", 5), ("a", 7), ("b", 3)]

        let res = wordFreqs.filter(
        {
            (e) -> Bool in

            if e.1 > 3 {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        }).map { $0.0 }

        print(res)
```

Gives Output:

```
["k","a"]
```

Comment: simple, first your array has been filtered _(by value > 3)_ then mapped _(for the key)_, you can read more about the Swift language from Apple's book.

Comment: If some one has any issue with my question. Please give comment rather than only negative mark.

Comment: I'd imagine the down vote is because this is a very simple question that can be answered by reading the first few pages of the free Swift book released by Apple. Asking the question here shows a lack of effort put into understanding the code before asking. (Not my down vote though. Just to be clear.)

Comment: I know that, but I want to understand it in simple manner. After searching about it when I felt the concept is not very much clear to me then I asked here. Is anything wrong in it?

Comment: You asked why the down vote. I'm providing a possible reason for it. I have no idea why someone actually down voted.

Comment: Better is to close this question rather than giving down votes.

Comment: I am not telling you as I am not mentioned your name. But I feel very bad.

Comment: I don't see why people down-voted this question. You need more than reading the first pages of the doc to understand it, as it includes many notions: tuples, filter, map, closures, function chaining, ... As, for one, up-voted it. I am convinced that SO is not reserved to senior programmers, and beginners are welcome here.

Comment: I know thats way I didn't accept any of the answer. As I want to accept all the answer but its not possible. SO, I have to choose the best one but I appreciate all the answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we take the parts of this code one after the other:

```
let wordFreqs = [("k", 5), ("a", 7), ("b", 3)]
```

You start with an array of **tuples**.

From the Swift documentation:

> A tuple type is a comma-separated list of types, enclosed in parentheses.

and:

> Tuples group multiple values into a single compound value. The values within a tuple can be of any type.

In this case, the tuples are "couples" of 2 values, one of type String and 1 of type Int.

---

```
        let res = wordFreqs.filter(
        {
            (e) -> Bool in
```

This part applies a filter on the array. You can see here that the closure of the filter takes an element e (so, in our case, one tuple), and returns a Bool. With the 'filter' function, returning true means keeping the value, while returning false means filtering it out.

---

```
            if e.1 > 3 {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
```

The `e.1` syntax returns the value of the tuple at index 1.
So, if the tuple value at index 1 (the second one) is over 3, the filter returns true (so the tuple will be kept) ; if not, the filter returns false (and therefore excludes the tuple from the result).
At that point, the result of the filter will be `[("k", 5), ("a", 7)]`

---

```
        }).map { $0.0 }
```

The map function creates a new array based on the tuple array: for each element of the input array ($0), it returns the tuple value at index 0. So the new array is `["k", "a"]`

---

```
        print(res)
```

This prints out the result to the console.

---

These functions (filter, map, reduce, etc.) are very common in functional programming. 
They are often chained using the dot syntax, for example, `[1, 2, 3].filter({ }).map({ }).reduce({ })`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: With pleasure! I'm still adding a few details to make it even more understandable.

Answer (score 8):

```
// this creates an array of tuples
let wordFreqs = [("k", 5), ("a", 7), ("b", 3)]

let res = wordFreqs.filter {
    (e) -> Bool in

    // this filters the array
    // it removes any items that have the second part of the tuple
    // of 3 or less
    if e.1 > 3 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}.map {
    // this "maps" the array and returns the first part of the tuple
    $0.0
}

print(res)
```

Note... if I was writing this I would shorten it to something like...

```
let res = wordFreqs.filter { $0.1 > 3 }
                   .map { $0.0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`wordFreqs` is array of `tuple`.

**Tuples**

> A tuple is a group of zero or more values represented as one value.

**For example** ("John", "Smith") holds the first and last name of a person. You can access the inner values using the dot(.) notation followed by the index of the value:

```
var person = ("John", "Smith")

var firstName = person.0 // John
var lastName = person.1 // Smith
```

Now in your case you have tuple with type `(String, Int)` and with `filter` you are comparing the `e.1 > 3`(Here `e` is holds the tuple value from the array iteration with `filter`) means thats `second(Int)` value is greater than 3.

Now after that your using `map` on the `filter` result and just retuning the `String($0.0)` from the tuple.

```
    //array of tuples
    let wordFreqs = [("k", 5), ("a", 7), ("b", 3)]

    let res = wordFreqs.filter(
    {
        (e) -> Bool in
        //Comparing the Second Int value of tuple in filter
        if e.1 > 3 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }

    })
    //Mapping the result of filter
    .map { 
         //return the String from the tuple
         $0.0 
    }
```

Comment: Nice! And what is "e" here? And When I run the code it will not go inside the filter method. why?

Comment: @Amanpreet Check the bracket statement in my answer: `e.1 > 3(Here e is holds the tuple value from the array iteration with filter)`

Comment: @Amanpreet Same goes for `map` also but in that place it is using `$0`.

Comment: @Amanpreet If you want remove code then it simply like `let res = wordFreqs.filter { $0.1 > 3 }.map { $0.0 }`

Answer (score 1):

Your `e` object representing `(String, int)` type. As you can see in array inside `[("k", 5), ("a", 7), ("b", 3)]`.

First of all you are using `filter` method so that's why you have to return `true` or `false` values. In this case you check if `e.1` (means int value) is greater than 3, if not you return false. After all that process the `filter` method return filtered array of (String,int) objects.

Next step is `map` function. In your case is simple it is just map all array values to first object of your tuple (String, int).

To understand better your code could look like this:

```
let filteredArray = wordFreqs.filter
({
    (e) -> Bool in
    return e.1 > 3
})// the filteredArray is [("k", 5), ("a", 7)]


let finalValue = filteredArray.map { 
  $0.0
}// here you're creating a new array with String. $0 represents object from filteredArray

print(finalValue) // ["k", "a"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand the concept.